# how to delete / modify a file in c

Tags: c, function

in my project "student management system" , two out of the functions i have requires that i create a temporary file ,copy the original file's content to it , except the line i want to modify or delete, and afterwards delete the old file and rename the temporary file (.tmp) to the old file name with (.txt),
when i run the program for the first time it works the file is changed renamed etc , but when i continue because its a loop , the second time the file isnt removed and the temporary file didnt change name , How can i make sure it the temporary file change name and the old one deleted ?

```
void deletestudent(FILE *fp){
  fflush(stdin);
 system("cls");
    fp=fopen("studentDB.txt","r");
        if (fp == NULL)
        printf("file not openned");
    FILE *ft=fopen("database.tmp","w");
    bool rt;
    int line,count;
    char buffer[100];
printf("\n");
printf("\n");
printf("\n");
 printf("\n");
 printf("\n");
 printf("\n");
  printf("\t\t\t 2. Delete a Student \n");
  printf("\t\t---------------------------------------------------------\t\t\t\t\t\t");
 printf("\n");
printf("\t\t\t ");
    printf("select student id \n");
 printf("\t\t\t ");
   scanf("%d",&line);
  count=0;
  while ((fgets(buffer, 1000, fp)) != NULL)
    {
        count++;// so that the counting start at 1

        /* If current line is line to replace */
        if (count == line){
          fputs("",ft);

        }
        else
            fputs(buffer,ft);
    }
    fclose(fp);

    fclose(ft);
//rt=remove("studentDB.txt");
    rename("database.tmp","studentDB.txt");
   // if(rt == TRUE)
     //   printf("not succesfull");
printf("\t\t\t\t");
    printf("deleted successfully  \n");

    system("pause");

}
```

i want to make sure that every time i call these functions that everything works no mattter how many times i use them

Comment: check all operating system return codes. More importantly `fopen` can return `NULL` (you're not checking the output, and when checking the input, you're doing nothing besides a print if it doesn't exist), `rename` can return nonzero so can `remove`. And yes, you need to remove before renaming

Comment: You need to post the exact code that the problem occurs with.  This is clearly not it because the `remove()` call is commented out.  Moreover if you want others to read your code, it is in your interest to make it readable, and indent _conventionally_ (rather than _randomly_).

Comment: As a general principle, given two files A and T (temporary) you might consider: rename A to B, rename T to A, delete B.  That way in the event that something fails or a power outage, you will not have lost data, and can use B to recover.  Checking the success of each operation before the next of course.

Comment: This code does not delete the old file, you have commented that out.  If that _is_ the actual code you are running (rather than the code you described), then clearly that is why it works only for in iteration - the one where studentDB.txt does not already exist.  You cannot rename a file to an existing name!

Comment: On mulitprocessing system (e.g. Linux) another process could (in principle) rename or overwrite the file....

Comment: `fflush(stdin)` invokes undefined behaviour. `fflush` expects an output stream, not an input stream.

Comment: re: "delete the old file and rename the temporary file".  You should probably change the way you think about the filesystem.  Suppose the name "foo" refers to a file, and you copy it (with some edits) to "foo.tmp".  If you then rename "foo.tmp" (using `rename`) to "foo", then the file that "foo" previously referred to will have its link count reduced by one and "foo" is now a name for the new file.  You do not need to "delete" anything.  You just manipulate the names.  See https://linux.die.net/man/3/rename

Answer (score 2):

Here is one way to do as you asked, borrowing from your existing code.
There are a few ways to do this.  Although this may not be the best way
according to all, pretty sure it is at least portable.  NOTE: It is not
foolproof:  note that fopen() can fail if a file is not accessable --
even though it exists.  That said, here is the compiled and tested code.
Please use at your own risk:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int file_exist(char *filename) 
{
    /* mode = "r": Opens for reading. If the file does not exist or cannot 
    ** be found, the fopen call fails.*/
    FILE *fp = fopen(filename,"r"); 
    if (!fp)
        return 0; /* NO: file does not exist/not found */
    fclose(fp); /* Found file and opened -- so close it*/
    return 1; /* YES: file exists, found */
}


void deletestudent(void)
{
    FILE *fp, *ft;
    fp=fopen("studentDB.txt","r");
    if (fp == NULL)
    {
        printf("file studentDB.txt not opened/found\n");
        return;
    }
    ft=fopen("database.tmp","w");
    if (ft == NULL)
    {
        printf("file database.tmp not opened/created\n");
        fclose(fp);  /* Close studentDB.txt */
        return;
    }

    /* ... perform copy ops, etc... (Code removed for brevity).*/

    fclose(fp);
    fclose(ft);
    remove("studentDB.txt");
    if(!file_exist("studentDB.txt"))
    {
        /*remove was successful, proceed with rename */
        printf("Removal of old studentDB.txt was successful.  Renaming\n");
        rename("database.tmp","studentDB.txt");
        if(!file_exist("database.tmp") && file_exist("studentDB.txt"))
        {
            printf("Rename of 'database.tmp' to 'studentDB.txt' was successful.\n");
        }
        else
        {
            printf("Rename of 'database.tmp' to 'studentDB.txt' FAILED!\n");
        }
    }
}

int main()
{
    deletestudent();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: i have implemented your code to my code it work but then it didnt database.tmp didnt chane name , and to make sure i added printf("file not remove") at the end and it show on the screen idk why it keeps happening

Comment: @melodic_n  -- please try pausing execution at every step (ie: system("pause") )... after 1.) opening "database.tmp", (pause)  ... and... 2.)  remove("studentDB.txt") (pause).... 3.) rename() ... every step.  At each pause, please check the folder and be sure to see if the files are being created, removed, renamed, etc, etc.   I had to do this same thing when testing the code, because the program starts and ends with the same result: only "studentDB.txt" exists.   Pausing was the only way I could be sure the program was working ... it is so fast.  Best wishes, please let us know ...

Comment: @melodic_n  -- if the system(pause) command doesn't help you find the pain point(s), then maybe it's time for a new question with your latest and newest code.  I'm sure the stackoverflow family will enjoy helping you again, you've been very polite.....